# How to alter this class object property text search so class does not need to be hardcoded

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

The following code is used to search a class object's properties for a text match.

I call it like so:

```
ClassPropertyTextSearchOrig<UserViewModel>.FullTextSearchInit();
if (FullTextSearch<UserViewModel>.Match((UserViewModel)item, searchValue))
{
    matchedItems.Add(item);
}
```

Class Property Search:

```
public static class ClassPropTextSearch<T>
{
    private static List<Func<T, string>> _properties;

    public static void FullTextSearchInit()
    {
        _properties = GetPropertyFunctions().ToList();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetPropertyFunctions()
    {
        var stringProperties = GetStringPropertyFunctions();
        return stringProperties;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> GetStringPropertyFunctions()
    {
        var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetProperty)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)).ToList();

        var properties = propertyInfos.Select(GetStringPropertyFunc);
        return properties;
    }

    public static Func<T, string> GetStringPropertyFunc(PropertyInfo propInfo)
    {
        ParameterExpression x = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        Expression<Func<T, string>> expression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(x, propInfo), x);
        Func<T, string> propertyAccessor = expression.Compile();
        return propertyAccessor;
    }

    public static bool Match(T item, string searchTerm)
    {
        bool match = _properties.Select(prop => prop(item)).Any(value => value != null && value.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));
        return match;
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is make it more dynamic, so that I can just pass the object's Type in and not hard-code the Object T.

Getting rid of the T and passing the Type in, is fine. But if I'm doing it like this, can someone help me with creating an efficient process. This may have tens of thousands of objects to iterate through. I'm a little lost as of how to start. Can I still save time by initializing some of it?

**[EDIT]**

This piece of code show how I get a list of property names that are bound to columns in a DataGrid. This is done each time there is a search as column order may change.

```
string binding_path = "";
var columnBoundProperties = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

//Gets list of column bound properties and their display index
foreach (var col in datagrid.Columns.Where(c => c.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible))
{
    var binding = (col as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding as Binding;
    binding_path = binding.Path.Path;
    columnBoundProperties.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(col.DisplayIndex, binding.Path.Path));
}

ClassPropTextSearch.Init(datagrid.Items[0].GetType(), columnBoundProperties)
var itemsSource = datagrid.Items as IEnumerable;
foreach (var item in itemsSource)
{
    int column_index_match = ClassPropTextSearch.FirstPropMatch(item, searchValue);
    if (column_index_match != null)
    {
        //Do something
        break;
    }
    //else continue searching items
}
```

As far as the object search goes I would still like to keep initialization side of things, so here is the mockup of that

```
public static class ClassPropTextSearch
{
    private static Type _itemType;
    private static List<KeyValuePair<int, PropertyInfo>> _stringProperties = new List<KeyValuePair<int, PropertyInfo>>();

    public static void init(Type itemType, List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> binding_properties)
    {
        _itemType = itemType;
        foreach (var prop in binding_properties)
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = _itemType.GetProperty(prop.Value);

            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    _stringProperties.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, PropertyInfo>(prop.Key, propertyInfo));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool Match(object item, string searchTerm)
    {
        return PropertiesMatch(item, searchTerm).Any();
    }

    public static string FirstPropMatch(object item, string searchTerm)
    {
        //return int index of first property match
    }

    private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> PropertiesMatch(object item, string searchTerm)
    {
        //return list of matches
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following version, major changes:

1. No need to pass in generic type explicitly
2. Store the list of string properties of the target type
3. **EDIT**: Support to find the first matching property's name

---

```
public static class ClassPropTextSearch
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, List<PropertyInfo>> _stringProperties =
        new Dictionary<Type, List<PropertyInfo>>();

    public static bool Match(object item, string searchTerm)
    {
        return PropertiesMatch(item, searchTerm).Any();
    }

    public static string FirstPropMatch(object item, string searchTerm)
    {
        var prop = PropertiesMatch(item, searchTerm).FirstOrDefault();
        return prop != null ? prop.Name : string.Empty;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> PropertiesMatch(object item, string searchTerm)
    {
        // null checking skipped...

        if (!_stringProperties.ContainsKey(item.GetType()))
        {
            // Retrieve and store the list of string properties of the input's type
            var stringProperties = item.GetType()
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetProperty)
                .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                .ToList();
            _stringProperties.Add(item.GetType(), stringProperties);
        }

        return _stringProperties[item.GetType()]
            .Where(prop => prop.GetValue(item, null) != null &&
                ((string)prop.GetValue(item, null)).ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));
    }
}
```

Usage is now simplified to:

```
if (ClassPropTextSearch.Match(item, searchValue))
{
    matchedItems.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: if I wanted to return the property name of the first property match it comes to, instead of a bool, how would you do this?

Comment: This is great thankyou! After thinking about the structure how you have setup _stringProperties, what if this only will hold one class type at a time, this means that the Type could be removed, and it probably should then be changed from a dictionary to list. I have my own index number that I would like to add in. Probably better if I write it up in an edit in the question.

Comment: I have added the edit below the original question, now that I know what I am after this mockup should help.

Comment: @Hank `FirstPropMatch()` returns the property name, and your `columnBoundProperties` is a [index, property name] pair, a simple lookup would give you the index. I wouldn't suggest to integrate the index thing in `ClassPropTextSearch`, after all it's used in GUI only. You've all the necessary bits & pieces, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Do it all transparently.

Don't pass in the `Type` - instead, just pass in the `object` you want to investigate. You can get the `Type` by calling `GetType()`.

Then, in your helper class (the one that does the searching) have a singleton `Dictionary` (or `ConcurrentDictionary`) which will key off the `Type` of the class to a class you create. Your class will look something like this (and will be immutable):

```
class StringProps
{
 PropertyInfo[] m_infos;
}
```

So now you have a list of StringPropertyInfo[] you create the same way you do in your code. (If the StringProps is missing in your Dictionary, you simply create it and add it). That way you have cached versions of all your properties and you can just use them to grab the relevant text strings off your object..

A few notes:

1. This simplistic approach is cool if you have a finite set of types you interrogate in this fashion. If your app generates types dynamically, this will be an ever-growing memory hog (though, to be fair, since you cannot unload dynamically created types, it almost doesn't matter).
2. If performance is still an issue after you do this, you may need to resort to emitting code that accesses the property and not via reflection. This can be done by utilizing `System.Linq.Expressions` and specifically `System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression` which will allow you to create a delegate that takes an object and casts it to the correct type, calling the correct property (thus not going thru reflection).

Comment: I am most interested in option two, could you provide an example please